# Is AVAudioPlayer able to loop large audio files without an audible gap?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I have large looping background music files of up to 10 minutes length. The sounds are looped perfectly and if the player introduces no delay you would not notice where the loop point is.

Can AVAudioPlayer play them without that the user will hear a gap caused by latency or other problems with looping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you don't stop/start it at the end and you set `numberOfLoops` to a negative integer, it should work.

Answer (score 4):

You might be hearing a delay because your music is compressed (mp3 for example). AVAudioPlayer has to decode the mp3 as it streams. If you had the same music in an uncompressed format, it would take significantly more disk space, but would loop seamlessly.

Answer (score 2):

I had problems trying to create seamless loops. I tried using the `numberOfLoops` property, with no success. I tried switching to uncompressed audio files, with no success. I even tried switching to an `AVAudioQueuePlayer`, queued with multiple instances of the same asset, with no success. In the end I solved the problem by creating two instances of `AVAudioPlayer` (player1 & player2) and switching between them. I began playback of player1 and used player2's `prepareToPlay` method, and the `play(atTime time:)` method setting the TimeInterval to `player1.deviceCurrentTime - player1.currentTime + player1.duration`. 
I then used the delegate method `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying` to prepare player1 to restart playback after player2 was done. To be honest, I don't know why this approach worked and simply setting `numberOfLoops` to -1 did not. But it may work for you also

Comment: `player1.duration`is not 100% accurate, to get full accuracy feed in your own duration through a hardcoded file or sometihng